# More than 12 columns in 12 column Foundation grid

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have this kind of structure:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-12 large-6 medium-12 panel-wrapper">
         Box no 1
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-12 large-6 medium-12 panel-wrapper">
         Box no 2
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-12 large-6 medium-12 panel-wrapper">
         Box no 3
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-12 large-6 medium-12 panel-wrapper">
         Box no 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Obviously row takes 2 columns, and I have 4 boxes. These boxes are variable height so Equalizer is not an option. What I want to do is let 3rd column below first column,and fourth column below second, but not in two rows since it would create big gaps. 
Is there a simple way to do this without using masonry or stuff like that, since Masonry isn't working as expected. It just stacks all columns on top of each other with absolute positioning and leaves it that way.

When they are same height it's not an issue. Works fine. But when first column is higher than second one, third column goes down below second column, and fourth column ends up below first one but with huge gap in height of third column.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you is the CSS3 Flexbox. You'll find all you need in here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It can makes your row or columns however you want very easily and makes things equal. Best thing for templating ever, included in CSS3 so doesn't make your application heavier with JS.